# Use .htaccess to rewrite a wildcard subdomain to a specific php file

Tags: htaccess, php, mod-rewrite

I want to use a particular page in my site as any subdomain. I need something like this `http://*.example.com/`.

So, as the user types `http://user1.example.com/` or `http://user2.example.com/` then the page must shown will be present in `http://example.com/profile.php`.

`http://user1.example.com/` must point to `http://example.com/profile.php` and **NOT REDIRECT**

Is it possible ?

Comment: Do you have the sub-domains assigned in your DNS and web server?

Comment: I need to do it via .htaccess dynamically.

Comment: You won't be able to without having the sub-domain defined and resolving to an IP address and the web server knowing that the sub-domains are sites on your server. From there, you can do anything you want .htaccess wise.

Comment: As closetnoc says. By the sounds of it you need a "wildcard subdomain" - does your host support this? Once that is set up and resolving then you can use .htaccess trickery.

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about sharding? Look at "Advanced Apache Rewriting" - at least probably your solution will use a **RewriteMap** .. although you do say *dynamically*, I still assume your list of users is static. [RewriteMap Apache Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) should be the way to go - you put your mapping in a text file like so:

```
Ralf.S.Engelschall    rse   # Bastard Operator From Hell
Mr.Joe.Average        joe   # Mr. Average
```

Then you define this map in the *.htaccess/apache-conf*:

```
RewriteMap real-to-user txt:/path/to/file/map.txt
```

Then you use that mapping in a rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/ex/(.*) ${examplemap:$1}
```

Another way - if you want to check inside that *profile.php* you mentioned - would be to do the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=site.example
RewriteRule ^ http://site.example/profile.php?host=%{HTTP_HOST}&uri=%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

You should have your setup so that your "catch all"-host has that RewriteRule, but your `site.example`-host is seperate and thus doesn't run into a loop. OFC you'll end up with people accessing `user1.site.example` and ending up with an address bar filled with `site.example/?was=user1.site.tld&uri=/`... If you need something different it's probably possible too though.

Comment: This will work only if your server is configured in a way such that *.domain.com resolves to the host with your rewrite rules. If you have that setup, then I am not sure you need any rewriting.

Comment: The sub domain is dynamic which are the usernames of the registered users.

Answer (score 2):

**Wildcard `VirtualHost`**

You can use a wildcard `VirtualHost` statement.

`<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /path/to/doc/root
    ServerName *.example.com
</VirtualHost>`

If you have a specific host, e.g. `www.example.com`, put its `VirtualHost` stanza above the wildcard one.  Apache works on a first match basis.

Also, you may want to add:

`DirectoryIndex profile.php`

to either a `.htaccess` or your `VirtualHost` if you want that file to be served up by default when no file is specified.

This will be needed to serve `profile.php` when a user type `http://*.example.com/`.

**DNS**

You can then setup a wildcard DNS entry for `*.example.com` or use CNAME/A record for each user.

Comment: Can it be possible only through .htaccess ? I have searched throughout the internet & got many codes but didnt got exactly what i am looking for.

Comment: The server has to be configured to route *.domain.com to your document root.   There are multiple ways to do that but it requires a server level change.  If you have a dedicated IP address it may work if the server maps that IP exclusively to your document root.  But you really need to find out how the server is setup.

Answer (score 0):

While searching through out the internet, i got this link.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13875273/dynamic-subdomain-with-htaccess-not-redirect

Here is the solution i got

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ /member.php?username=%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?contact$ /contact.php?username=%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^.]+)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?album/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)$ /album.php?username=%1&title=$1&album_id=$2 [L]
```

But it is exactly not same as my requirement. I need to change this code as my need.